# Python: How to slice a string on a specific number of characters into a list?

Tags: python, slice

I am reading a line of text data and I want to split the line into a list of values.  For example the line has four numbers, each one allotted 5 spaces, so if the numbers are 18, 295, -9999, and 1780 then the original line will look like this (with ^ characters denoting the start and end of line, not included in actual input data):

```
^   18  295-9999 1780^
```

I want to split the line into a list of its actual component values:

```
[18, 295, -9999, 1780]
```

I know the number of values that the list should contain (in the example above it's 4), and I know exactly how many spaces each value takes up in the string (in the example above it's 5).  I can create a loop to do this splitting, like this:

```
values = []
for i in range(4):
    values.append(line[i*5:5])
```

Is there a more efficient or more "Pythonic" way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Using slicing...

```
>>> [int(s[i:i+5]) for i in xrange(0, len(s), 5)]
[18, 295, -9999, 1780]
```

Or - if you really wanted to, some people find `re` a bit more readable... (just throwing this in as an alternative for reference - don't shoot me!)

```
>>> map(int, re.findall('.{5}', s))
[18, 295, -9999, 1780]
```

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was after, thanks!  BTW readability is key, especially since I'm new to Python and I'll have to maintain this code for a while, so thanks for the alternative you posted using re.

Comment: @James any competent programmer will realise what the slice operation is doing anyway - so I wouldn't worry too much about that

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution:

```
x = '   18  295-9999 1780'

def split_up(x):
    return map(int, x.replace('-', ' -').split())
```

Result

```
>>> split_up(x)
[18, 295, -9999, 1780]
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot.  But, it will fail if given a five digit positive number in one of the 4 bins.